# how to find the file which is created today?

Tags: shell

I want to get the files which are created on today's date into a particular directory. i'm using the below command but it is throwing error :-

**find . -mtime -1 -type f -print /var/options**

How to achieve that ?

Comment: `into a particular directory` Which directory? `.` or `/var/options`? `but it is throwing error` what error? Please copy the error verbatim into the quesiton.

Comment: error is : 
find: paths must precede expression: /var/options and the directory is /var/options

Comment: Then you want `find /var/options -mtime -1 -type f -print`, no? Also `-mtime -1` will find files modified in last 24 hours which is  __not__ today (unless it's exactly 00:00).

Comment: is there a command which can give files created for today's date or file created one hour back?

Comment: `find` has big documentation - see `man find`. Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
minutes_since_midnight=$(( ($(date +%s) - $(date -d '00:00' +%s))/60 ))
find /var/options -type f -mmin -"$minutes_since_midnight"
```

Comment: this will give files created in last one hour?

Comment: The name `minutes_since_midnight` could be a hint. No, it should give files since today midnight.